# Setting case-insensitivity for bash completion on a command-by-command basis

Tags: bash, case-insensitive, tab-completion

Is there a way to specify that a particular command has case insensitivity, without turning on case insensitivity globally (at least for that shell)?

In my particular case, I have a small app that gives me command line access to a database of email addresses, so I type:

```
db get email john smith
```

and it returns back with John Smith's email address.  So I've managed to enable completion largely inside the app: setting

```
COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "$(db --complete $COMP_CWORD "$COMP_WORDS[@]"}")" -- ${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}))
```

works to allow me to tab-complete `get` and `email`.  However, if I then type `j<tab>`, it refuses, because in the email database, it's properly capitalised.  I'd like to get bash to complete this anyway.  (If I use a capital `J`, it works.)

Failing that, I can have my `--complete` option change the case of its reply by matching the input, I suppose, but ideally the command line would match the database if at all possible.

Note that I have this working inside the app when using readline, it's only interfacing with bash that seems to be an issue.

Answer (score 6):

Indeed there seems to be no way to have `compgen` do case-insensitive matching against the word list (`-W`).
I see the following workarounds:

Simple solution: Translate both the word list and the input token to all-lowercase first.
Note: This is *only* an option if it's acceptable to *have all completions turn into all-lowercase*.

```
complete_lower() {

    local token=${COMP_WORDS[$COMP_CWORD]}
    local words=$( db --complete $COMP_CWORD "${COMP_WORDS[@]}" )

    # Translate both the word list and the token to all-lowercase.
    local wordsLower=$( printf %s "$words" | tr [:upper:] [:lower:] )
    local tokenLower=$( printf %s "$token" | tr [:upper:] [:lower:] )

    COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "$wordsLower" -- "$tokenLower"))   
}
```

Better, but more elaborate solution: Roll your own, case-insensitive matching logic:

```
complete_custommatch() {

    local token=${COMP_WORDS[$COMP_CWORD]}
    local words=$( db --complete $COMP_CWORD "${COMP_WORDS[@]}" )

    # Turn case-insensitive matching temporarily on, if necessary.
    local nocasematchWasOff=0
    shopt nocasematch >/dev/null || nocasematchWasOff=1
    (( nocasematchWasOff )) && shopt -s nocasematch

    # Loop over words in list and search for case-insensitive prefix match.
    local w matches=()
    for w in $words; do
        if [[ "$w" == "$token"* ]]; then matches+=("$w"); fi
    done

    # Restore state of 'nocasematch' option, if necessary.
    (( nocasematchWasOff )) && shopt -u nocasematch

    COMPREPLY=("${matches[@]}")
}
```

Comment: The above solution does not seem to be entirely correct as it returns only first match instead of all matches. removing the "break" should solve that. Another problem is that this does not work gracefully on older bash versions which do not have nocasematch option at all. I don't know what would be the best solution for that, but I used in my script

    local SHOPT=$( shopt -p )
    local IGNORE_CASE=0
    [[ "${SHOPT#*shopt -u nocasematch}" == "$SHOPT" ]] || IGNORE_CASE=1

Comment: Thanks, @Neuron: I've updated the code to return all matches. As for the `nocasematch` option not being available (do you know in what version it was introduced?): One could use your test and then, in the absence of the option, apply the ` tr [:upper:] [:lower:]` technique in the body of the `for` loop. A slightly more concise way of performing the option-availability test is: `local haveNoCaseMatch=0 \n [[ -z "$(shopt -q nocasematch 2>&1)" ]] && haveNoCaseMatch=1
`

Comment: You should write that as COMPREPLY=("${matches[@]}") otherwise it will break up multi-word options (eg, filenames)

Comment: Thanks, @Orwellophile; I've updated my answer. It's a good idea to double-quote even with *single*-word options - which is the typical case and the case at hand - so as to prevent accidental shell expansions of chars. such as '*' and '?'.

Comment: true.  quotes are to bash what condoms are to sex... it's much more exciting when you know you can get away without using them... and when you're wrong, you don't always know about it right away...

Comment: Intead of messing up with shopt you can use a little bash magic: "${w,,}" and "${token,,}". :)

Comment: @AlexeyVoinov: Thanks; yes, that's an option if your'e using bash **4+** (OSX is still on bash 3.x, for instance).

Answer (score 2):

It's a lot easier to just use `grep` to do all the work; then the case is preserved in the completions, and you don't have to mess with `shopt` or anything like that. For example:

```
_example_completions () {
    local choices="john JAMES Jerry Erik eMIly alex Don donald donny@example.com RON"
    COMPREPLY=( $( echo "$choices" | tr " " "\n" | grep -i "^$2" ) )
}
```

Here, `$choices` is your list of words, `tr` is used to change the spaces between words to newlines so `grep` can understand them (you could omit that if your words are already newline-delimited), the `-i` option is case insensitive matching, and `"^$2"` matches the current word (bash passes it as `$2`) at the beginning of a line.

```
$ example dO<tab>
Don     donald     donny@example.com
```